# Morgen + Präteritum. Verwirrt über die Interpretationsweise

Tags: tense, preterite

Ich wurde gerade auf einem Deutschlernserver gebeten, zu erklären, wie man den Satz *Morgen musste alles stimmen.* zu interpretieren hat. Der Satz erscheint mir vollkommen natürlich und liest sich von der Bedeutung her so etwas im Sinne von “Wenn es morgen nicht alles stimmt, dann wird es schlimme Konsequenzen geben.” oder “Es darf nicht dazu kommen, dass morgen nicht alles stimmt”.

Allerdings fühle ich mich äusserst verwirrt davon. Wieso wird hier ein Präteritum für ein zukünftiges Ereignis verwendet? Ich finde manche (wenige) Beispiele der Konstruktion online, aber keine Beschreibungen oder Erklärungen.

Was ist die genaue Bedeutung dieser Konstruktion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es handelt sich um eine Tempusverschiebung in die Vergangenheit und um eine Perspektiv-Verschiebung in die Erlebens- und Gedankenwelt der Person, die diesen Satz dachte, möglicherweise auch in der berichteten Situation gesagt hat. Als erzählerischer Kunstgriff wird diese Art des Tempus- und Perspektivgebrauchs "***erlebte Rede***" genannt. Dieser Bezeichnung zum Trotz handelt es sich jedoch meist nicht um '*Rede*', sondern um die *Gedanken* der gerade in der Erzählung fokussierten Person.

Ein Beispiel, im Präsens erzählt, bereits aus der Perspektive der Figur:

Karl **geht** noch einmal alles durch: **Werden** genug Getränke da **sein**? **Ist** die Band für die richtige Zeit **bestellt**? Und **hat** der Onkel der Braut wirklich **zugesagt**, anstelle des Vaters die Rede des Brautvaters zu halten, weil die Stimmbandentzündung des Vaters noch nicht **abgeklungen ist**? Karl **weiß**, morgen **muss** alles stimmen, einen solchen Fehlschlag wie beim letzten Mal **wird** ihm niemand mehr verzeihen.

Das übliche Erzähltempus für narrative Texte ist im Deutschen das Präteritum. In einer Erzählung oder einem Roman werden alle Tempusformen parallel in die analogen Vergangenheitstempora verschoben:

- Präsens > Präteritum
- Perfekt > Plusquamperfekt
- Futur > 'würde'-Futur

Somit erhalten wir:

Karl **ging** noch einmal alles durch: **Würden** genug Getränke da **sein**? **War** die Band für die richtige Zeit **bestellt**? Und **hatte** der Onkel der Braut wirklich **zugesagt**, anstelle des Vaters die Rede des Brautvaters zu halten, weil die Stimmbandentzündung des Vaters noch nicht **abgeklungen war**? Karl **wusste**, morgen **musste** alles stimmen, einen solchen Fehlschlag wie beim letzten Mal **würde** ihm niemand mehr verzeihen.

Während die *indirekte Rede* ('er sagte, dass ...') Konjunktivformen benutzen kann:

> er sagte, dass morgen alles stimmen müsse

(was in der gesprochenen Sprache von heute jedoch seltener wird, man bevorzugt meist den Indikativ):

> er meinte, dass morgen alles stimmen muss

oder, noch einfacher:

> er meinte noch vor dem Weggehen, morgen muss aber alles stimmen!,

ist das Basistempus der erlebten Rede in aller Regel der Indikativ des Präteritums.

---

Eine Erläuterung der erlebten Rede und anderer Formen der Rede- und Gedankenwiedergabe findet sich in der Duden-Grammatik 2006 auf den Seiten 529 bis 535.

Answer (score 6):

Es handelt sich hier offensichtlich um einen Satz in der Vergangenheit. Zu diesem Zeitpunkt (ausgehend von heute) hat jemand gedacht, dass am darauffolgenden Tag "alles stimmen" musste.

Sowohl der Zeitpunkt, als dies gedacht wurde, als auch das von diesem Zeitpunkt gesehene "morgen" liegen für uns als Leser in der Vergangenheit.