# Is this inconsistent use of the subjunctive II?

Tags: subjunctive

Here are two consecutive sentences from Chapter 8 of Donna Leon's novel, Acqua Alta:

> Brunetti rechnete sich bereits aus, daß es ihn nur auf dem Weg von und zur Arbeit berühren **würde**, wenn er am Fuß der Rialtobrücke über den Campo San Bartolomeo mußte.
>   Glücklicherweise lag die Gegend um die Questura so hoch, daß sie nur bei allerschlimmster Flut überschwemmt **wurde**.

I do not see any reason for preferring the subjunctive II usage in the first and not in the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see, Brunetti has just noticed the changing weather. So the sentence could be simplified to:

> Eine Aqua Alta **würde** ihn kaum berühren.

With "rechnete sich aus, dass ..." this is reinforced.

The "..., wenn er...über...musste" is a bit risky, but here it is no problem at all. There is only the auxiliary "musste"; it refers directly to his "Weg zur Arbeit".

It does not matter if he has to wet his socks at the Rialto Bridge, or if he can take a detour. The disturbance is there.

The "würde" stays even when you change it to:

> Eine *Aqua Alta* **würde** ihn kaum berühren, **ausser bei** der Rialto
>   Brücke, auf dem Weg zur Arbeit und zurück.

---

> Glücklicherweise lag die Gegend um die Questura so hoch, daß sie nur
>   bei allerschlimmster Flut überschwemmt wurde.

Despite the emotional first word, this is a fact: it happens  2 or 3 times per century, as experience shows.

This "allerschlimmste" is a bit baroque; it is not specific, unless in a statistical sense. *Rekordflut*?

If you choose a hypothetical kind of flood, it changes  to *konjunktiv*:

> Glücklicherweise lag die Gegend um die Questura so hoch, daß sie nur
>   bei **einem Tsunami** überschwemmt **würde**.

The added article also helps make it unique/hypothetical. Here it might even be "spelled out" to clearly show the irreal aspect: "...bei einem Tsunami überschwemmt **werden würde**".

Answer (score 3):

These sentences differ along two dimensions: Firstly, with regard to what kind of auxiliary *werden* they have, and second, with regard to the context.

German has different kinds of *werden*. Looking only at the auxiliaries, we have:

- future auxiliary *wird* (+ infinitive)
- subjunctive auxiliary *würde* (+ infinitive)
- passive auxiliary *wird, wurde, würde* (+ past participle)

Of these, only the passive auxiliary occurs in all tenses and moods.

In the second sentence, we have the **passive auxiliary** in the past indicative.

> Die Gegend lag so hoch, daß die Brücke selten **überschwemmt wurde**.

There is nothing that would license a subjunctive here.*

This is different for the first sentence.

> Er rechnete sich aus, daß das Wasser ihn auf dem Weg **berühren würde**.

As *sich ausrechnen* indicates, the sentence is about reported thought. Here, *würde* is the **subjunctive auxiliary**. Its function is to represent the future auxiliary in the context of reported thought (*erlebte Rede*; see [this excellent answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/46276/35111)). The matching direct sentence would be:

> Brunetti rechnete sich aus: "Das Wasser **wird** mich auf dem Weg berühren."

---

* *Würde* as a combined subjunctive and passive auxiliary or *werden würde* with the functions split among the two words is possible if we change the context.

> Der Ingenieur überlegte. Die Gegend lag so hoch, daß die Brücke wohl kaum überschwemmt **würde** / **werden würde**.

This reports the engineer's expectations in a similar fashion to the first sentence above.

Comment: I thougt about this as well. However, if the direct speech was in future tense, why subjunctive II (*würde*) instead of I (*werde*), and why would the verb in the other part of the *wenn*-sentence be in indicative (*musste*) instead of subjunctive (*müsse*) mood?

Comment: @amadeusamadeus 1. I removed the subordinate *wenn* clause because *würde* would occur without it as well. 2. It can't be indirect speech, because that would not be limited to *würde*: *Er sagte, er wird/werde/würde sich darum kümmern*. 3. My use of the term *reported thought* may be misleading (in that people will think I meant *indirect speech*); my point is that *würde* represents the future auxiliary in this context, as it does in *erlebte Rede*: *Hans rieb sich die Hände. Er würde sich das Geld zurückholen.*

Answer (score 2):

**No, it isn't**.

Subjunctive II is used when something is not real, at least not currently.

The first sentence talks about a possibility which, by using subjunctive II, is described as not real. The second sentence is about a real, although rare, event.

Compare the following sentences:

> Wenn es regnet, brauche ich einen Regenschirm.

Here the rain is presented as a possibility that can be real.

> Wenn es regnen würde, bräuchte ich einen Regenschirm.

Here the rain is only a theoretical possibility, but not real.